# How to get all the contents of df -h command as string

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, disk-usage, java

I want to have a CRON job which calls a Java program to send a mail if disk space is more than 80%.

Along with it, I want to send the contents of the `df -h` command also. What I did was create a vaiable in bash like this:

`DISK_SPACE = ($(df -h))`

I am passing this to my java program like this:

`java com.myproject.alerting.DiskSpaceAkert $DISK_SPACE`

Instead of the whole output of the `df -h` command, I am getting a parital output for it.
If this is my original output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G   17M  1.6G   2% /run
/dev/sda1        29G  5.1G   24G  18% /
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
```

I am getting only `Filesystem      Size  Used` in my Java args.

How do I send the whole output?

Comment: Java is an awful resource-heavy method to simply send an email.  You could just use a shell script to test disk use > 80% and then call... df -h | /usr/bin/mailx -s "Disk Space Alert!" user@example.com

Comment: `DISK_SPACE = ($(df -h))` will result in `bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('` !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441304/collect-linux-command-output

Comment: https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-java/

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash, instead of playing with Java.

```
#!/bin/bash
admins_mail=youraddress@example.com
quota_exceeded=80
df -h | grep -vE 'hostname_or_IP_address:/mount/point|tmpfs|cdrom|Used' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | while read output; do 
status=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1 ) 
echo $status
partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' ) 
if [ $status -ge $quota_exceeded ]; then 
  echo  "Alert: Almost out of disk space $status" 
  df -h | mail -s "Alert: out of disk space $status" $admins_mail
fi 
done
```

or one liner:

```
#!/bin/bash
df -Ph $f |awk 'NR >1{gsub("%","",$0);print }'| awk -v subject="$subject" '{if($(NF-1)>80){print "mailx -s disk quota exceeded 80% of space in "$NF  " youraddress@example.com |sh"} else{print "No disk space issue exists"}}'| sed "s/out/'out/g" |sed "s/.* /&'  /g"
```

Comment: One liners are often unmaintainable. Keep with a readable script

Comment: I am Linux sysadmin, not a newbie. I gave the choice. And you are not right. They are maintainable if you know commands and what they are doing. If you want use Linux, learn awk, sed, grep, egrep and other commands. Simple as that.

Comment: This isn't about you. Or me. It's about writing answers that are useful to the OP, who clearly isn't an expert with shell scripting, and others in the future. I'll remove my comments if you like, but please consider what I've written here

Comment: I understand. But everyone who wants to use Linux, should learn basic commands and how to use them in the terminal. One liners seems difficult only for newbies.

Answer (score -1):

`` result=`command` ``  or `result=$(command)` both assign the output of command to the result variable.

Comment: This is only a partial answer as it does not address the fact that the variable is used unquoted in the call to the Java code.

Comment: Not only that, `DISK_SPACE` is declared as an array variable but the equivalent scalar is passed to the java app, which is why it's only providing the first element